# setSupportActionBar cannot be applied

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am trying to use toolbar in my app,
for this purpose i have create a xml file name
my_action_bar

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_action_bar_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    >
<ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imgageView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/dog"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //action bar toolbar
    Toolbar actionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_action_bar_toolbar);
    //important that is set first
    setSupportActionBar(actionBarToolbar);
```

but it shows an error line on set support action bar
set support action bar cannot be applied
[image: Error line]

How to resolve this error
I am using Min API is 11
Any suggestion will be appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show you imports ?

Comment: @Logic
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

Comment: did u set your theme in styles.xml  to android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"

Comment: i think you have use `android.widget.Toolbar` instead of import `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`..

Comment: i think you have use `android.widget.Toolbar` instead of import `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`..

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to change your import from,

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

to

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

or

In `Androidx` you can use

`import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;`

This will surely solve the problem.

Comment: If you have any more problem, just let me know, I will be sure to help.

Comment: Perfect. What would I do without this site.

Answer (score 2):

Change your import to

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Answer (score -2):

Hey? Navigate to app>res>values>styles.xml
Change

```
<style name = "AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name = "AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

I hope this helps you 
Nice coding